# why does a pointer to an array of string literals reverse the index ordering?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

Alright so I have a array of string literals

```
char* messages[] = {
    "t",
    "123",
    "test3",
    "test4",
    "test5", 
    "test1000"
};
```

I want to make a pointer to the array, I make it like so:

```
char *(*p)[6] = &messages;
```

I was wondering why is it that

```
p[0][3];
```

returns "test4" when

```
messages[3];
```

returns "test4"

also

```
p[1][3];
```

returns a seg fault. 
Im pretty perplexed by this behavior, I was hoping one of you could explain it.

Comment: Becuz "Undefined Behavior".

Comment: That should not compile. _error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'char *(*)[4]' with an rvalue of type 'char *(*)[6]'_ In C, it's a warning, but still, pay attention to the warnings.

Comment: @chis *edited I copy and pasted code from another test I did.

Comment: It's difficult to see how `messages[1]` could result in "test4".  Please provide a minimal test-case.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth edited again, my apologizes, Its all good now

Comment: @JakeSchievink - `Alright so I have a 2d array of characters `  That is not a 2d array of charaters.  That is a 1 dimensional array of string literals.

Comment: What behavior did you expect and where do you see reverse index ordering?

Comment: `p` is not array, it's a pointer to array. It means you need to dereference it before you can access your strings. Standart way to do it: `(*p)[n]`. `p[0][n]` will also work, because `p[0] == *(p+0) == *p`. `p[1]` is undefined behavior, because `p` is pointer to single array (`char(*)[6]`), not array of arrays.

Comment: And `p[0][0]` does return what, please?  `"test1000"`? I doubt it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: To be pedantic, that is an array of *pointers*. Literals are arrays of characters, and that is clearly not an array of arrays of characters.

Comment: @JakeSchievink - `I want to make a pointer to the array, because the number of chars in each array in the 2d array is dynamic` I'm still trying to wrap my head around why you think using a pointer automatically makes things "dynamic".   I really don't see the utility in what you're doing, to be perfectly honest.  Maybe you (or someone else) can explain?...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I could be, and probably am, completely misunderstanding this. But with a pointer I dont need to declare any max columns in the array. so I can do `char *(*p)[6] = &messages;` instead of char `*p[somethingfixed][6] = &messages;`

Comment: @JakeSchievink - Well, it's the `6` that determines the number of strings, no?  So regardless of how you cut it, what you want is not dynamic, and as explained by the wealth of answers, the `[somethingfixed]` is invalid outside of index `0`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ya it makes alot more sense now. Is there a way I can point to messages without needing to add the `6`?

Comment: @JakeSchievink - C++ programmers would start out using `std::vector<std::string>`. That construct is truly dynamic.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm asking more out of curiosity now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
char *(*p)[6] = &messages;
```

defines `p` to be a pointer that points to *an array of 6 pointers to char*.

That means:

```
*p == messages
p[0] == messages

(*p)[3] == messages[3]
p[0][3] == messages[3]
```

However, `p[1]` is invalid since `p` is not an array. You are going to see undefined behavior (segmentation violation error is one such behavior) if you use `p[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `p` is a pointer to the *whole* array. `p[0]` is equivalent to `*p` which is the array itself. It is expected that `(*p)[3] == p[0][3] == messages[3]`, that is just the semantics of pointers in general. `p[1][3]` causes a segmentation fault as you are using a pointer to a single object `messages` as if it was an array of them, and indexing the second element that does not exist.